# Function not initializing

Tags: c, arrays, function

Hi I have problem with initializing my function for printing an error message if some numbers in an array are same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printRepeating(int arr[], int size)
{
  int i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for(j = i+1; j < size; j++)
      if(arr[i] == arr[j])
        printf("Wrong input. Same numbers in array!\n");
}     

int main()
{
    int arr[200],i;
    int res, num;
    while((res = scanf("%d", &num)) == 1)
    {
      arr[i++] = num;
      if(num == 0){
        break;
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++)
      printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[0]);  
    printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
    return 0;
}
```

If I scan `1 2 3 1 4 5 0`, my function `printRepeating` wont start nevertheless I have numbers `1 1` that are same in the array, Why ? And another problem is when I type `1 2 3 1 5 0` it only prints `1 2 3` and for example I when I scan `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0` it prints all numbers except for 0.

Comment: Is the issue resolved ? Please mark the answer as accepted if it did. @blackroad

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code. First, initialize `i` to be `0`, and declare a new variable `j` alongside `i`,

```
int arr[200], i = 0, j;
```

The size of your array would simply be `i`, which you increment every time you insert an element in the array, and change this,

```
for(i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++)
     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

to this

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
      printf("%d ", arr[j]);
```

since the size of your array is stored in variable `i`. Also, the way you are calculating the size of your array is wrong which returns `1` everytime since the numerator and denominator are the same. Generally, it is `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, and in this case, it too, would return `200`, since the size of your declared array is `200`, but since you increment your `i` every time at insertion, simply set your `arr_size` to be `i`.

```
int arr_size = i;
```

Comment: I suppose your issue is resolved, please mark this answer if it solved your issue. @blackroad

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int arr_size = sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

does not do what you are expecting. You are only dividing the size of two elements of the array, which are always the same size, thus always giving `1` as result. If you want to give the number of elements to the function, give it a variable that you used to count each number as you read them.

Also this:

```
for(i = 0; i < arr[i]; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

Is only printing numbers that are not larger than their indices. Again, your program is missing a variable to count the number of input values.